# javascript function save to cookies

Tags: php, javascript

For now, i have a function macs, and i need to implement this function to save inside a cookie and have it stored in mysql..

So how am i supposed to have this function together?

```
        <script language="JavaScript">

        function getMacAddress(){
          document.macaddressapplet.setSep( "-" );
          return (document.macaddressapplet.getMacAddress());
        }

        function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays)
        {
        var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays);
        document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+ ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
        }

        setCookie('cookie_name','getMacAddress()','1');
        </script> 
        <body>

        <?php
         //Defaults to 1
        $javascript_cookie = isset($_COOKIE["cookie_name"]) ? $_COOKIE["cookie_name"] : 1;
        echo "$javascript_cookie";

        // db insert query
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbname = 'registration';
        mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser) or die("Could not connect database");
        mysql_select_db($dbname);
        $sql_query = mysql_query("SELECT * from user WHERE UserID ='".$_POST['newUserID']."'");
        $sql = "INSERT INTO test(mac) VALUES ('".$javascript_cookie."')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        ?>
```

Comment: I can't recall a more poorly worded question.

Comment: Tell us just what it is that needs to be stored as a cookie.  Is it the return value of the getMacAddress function?  Is it the function definition itself?

Maybe you could add some comments in the code on what needs to be done, with what.

Comment: i need to store macs.getMacAddress into the cookie so that i can have it display on the web and have it save into mysql

Comment: @Pointy: ever browse through the lowest-voted questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=31910&sort=votes

Answer (score 2):

Here are the two functions I use to handle cookies:

```
function writeCookie(name,value,days) {
    var date, expires;
    if (days) {
        date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();}
    else{
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var i, c, ca, nameEQ = name + "=";
    ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

- **name** is the name of the information you want to store
- **value** its value
- **days** is to set and expiration date or not if empty

Answer (score 0):

Use a Javascript library like [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org) or [JQuery](http://jquery.com). They have good simpliefied interfaces for common functionality like this, and hide most of the messy cross-browser compatibility issues behind their API.

Comment: i have a function for that,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115690/javascript-calling-function

but its not working, can you take alook?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the JavaScript/setCookie part, if you replace 'Text3123234' with getMacAddress(), that should get you started.  So that line should look like:

```
setCookie('cookie_name', getMacAddress(), 1);
```

Comment: Edited the post again, this is what ive now.. but the output turns out to be a value of "1" instead of mac address...

Comment: You need to remove the quotes from the call to getMacAddress in the setCookie call. otherwise the value of the cookie will be the string 'getCookie()'.

Please post what you get if you put the following call before the setCookie call:

    alert("MAC address is " + getMacAddress());